# How does this type of loop work: `for (; x++;);`

Tags: c

How does this type of loop work and why is it printing `x=1`; instead `x=3` ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char x = 2;
    for (; x++;);
    printf("x=%d", x);
}
```

Comment: I know I already saw this question earlier today.

Comment: What is `Int` in `Int main(){`? That cannot work. Why don't you do copy & paste?

Comment: `error: unknown type name ‘Int’; did you mean ‘int’?`

Comment: Try to follow the loop execution with a pencil and paper. You can make this easier if you insert a newline between `for(;x++;)` and `;`.

Comment: Also note  `for(;STH;)` is equivalent to `while(STH)`.

Answer (score 9):

After `Int` is corrected to `int`, the loop `for(;x++;);` will execute the null statement `;` until `x++` evaluates as false (zero).

Since `x` starts at two, it is incremented to three, then four, and so on. This continues until `x` reaches the maximum value of a `char`. Then adding one yields a value that `char` cannot represent.<sup>1</sup> This number is then converted to `char` for storing in `x`.

If `char` is unsigned, this conversion wraps to zero, so zero is stored in `x`. If `char` is signed, the result of the conversion is implementation-defined (or a signal is raised). A typical result is to wrap to the minimum `char` value, commonly −128. In this case, the loop then proceeds to increment `x` through −127, −126, and so on, until it reaches zero.

Thus, in either of the common cases above, `x` eventually reaches zero. Then the next evaluation of `x++` increments `x` to one and evaluates to zero. Then the loop exits, and `printf("x=%d",x);` prints “x=1”.

Other behaviors are possible. For example, a C implementation could define the conversion of an out-of-range value to `char` to produce 127, and then the loop would not terminate. (Interestingly, though, the rule in C 2018 6.8.5 6 allows a compiler to assume the loop terminates, even though actually executing it would not.)

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> The arithmetic is done in the `int` type, so it does not overflow (except in hypothetical bizarre C implementations where `char` is the same width as `int`). In specifying the postfix `++` operator, C 2018 6.5.2.4 2 refers to the additive and assignment operators, which promote `char` operands to `int`.

Comment: Pretty thorough answer... on those rare architectures where `char` has the same width as `int` and is signed, `x++` has undefined behavior when `x` has the value `INT_MAX`, which allows the compiler to assume the the loop never ends :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(;x++;);
```

This is a loop with no body.
It will stop when `x++` evaluates to `False (0)`.
Because `x` starts at `2`, and has type `char`, it will (most likely) increment to +127, then wrap around to -128, then increment to up to `0`, when the loop finally ends.

(As the commenters point out, wrap-around on signed types is not part of the spec, and is technically implementation-defined behavior.  But most common implementations do wrap around in a predictable fashion.)

When the loop is finally done, the value of `x` is `1`, due to the post-increment, and the value will be printed out.

The final output will be: `x=1`

Comment: This is not a loop with no body. This is a loop with an empty body.

Comment: It will output `x=1` because the loop exits when `x++` evaluates to 0, which will increment x again to 1.

Comment: You guys appreciate your help 

Comment: @Kevin: The behavior is implementation-defined, not undefined. The specification for postfix `++` refers to the additive and assignment operators, and those promote `char` to `int` and do the arithmetic in the int type, without overflow (in normal C implementations). Then the result is converted back for assignment, and conversion of an out-of-range value to a signed integer type is implementation-defined, not undefined.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That's interesting, thanks. I found an SO answer from a few years ago that explains it in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

This code relies on overflow behaviour, and I think with signed types (which `char` possibly can be) this is undefined behaviour.

But if it isn't, the following works:

```
char x=2;
```

x gets assigned 2.

```
for(;x++;);
```

This is a loop with an empty method body and its break condition `x++`. You could as well write `while (x++);`.

It loops, doing nothing but incrementing `x`, until x evaluates "false" (0) before incrementing:

- It gets the value (2) and increments. This value is != 0, so repeat.
- It gets the value (3) and increments. This value is != 0, so repeat.
- It gets the value (4) and increments. This value is != 0, so repeat.
- ...
- It gets the value (127) and increments. This value is != 0, so repeat.
- It gets the value (128 if unsigned, -128 if signed AND the overflow behaviour is "two-s complement") and increments. This value is != 0, so repeat.
- It gets the value (255 if unsigned, -1 if signed) and increments. This value is != 0, so repeat.
- It gets the value (0) and increments. The value is == 0, so break the loop.

That last increment makes `x` have the value 1.

Thus,

```
printf("x=%d",x);
```

prints `x=1`.

Answer (score -1):

char uses one byte of memory. So, its range is from -128 to 127.

```
char x=2;
for(;x++;);
```

This loop will run for values x = {2, 3, ..., 127, -128, -127, ..., -1, 0}.

As soon as x becomes 0, the condition check will stop the loop but the increment will also take place.

Hence, 0 becomes 1 and hence 1 will be printed.

Comment: "its range is from -128 to 127" -- only if it's signed. `char` may be signed or unsigned by default.

Comment: The step from x==127 to x==-128 is udefined, so the `As soon as x becomes 0' is an unfounded supposition.

Comment: @CiaPan: That step is not undefined. It is implementation-defined. The specification for postfix `++` refers to the additive and assignment operators, and those promote `char` to `int` (in normal C implementations) and do the arithmetic in the `int` type, without overflow. Then the result is converted back for assignment, and conversion of an out-of-range value to a signed integer type is implementation-defined, not undefined.